# ¿Cómo seleccionar hoja de excel para importarla a un DataGridView en C#?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

Logré importartar un archivo excel a un 'DataGridView', solo que tengo un problema, me gustaría poder importar cualquier archivo 'Excel' sin importar el nombre de la hoja por que por ahora solo puedo importar archivos que tengan como nombre [Sheet$].

Este es mi código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace ImportarExcelToDatagridview
{
    class Importar
    {
        OleDbConnection conn;
        OleDbDataAdapter MyDataAdapter;
        DataTable dt;

        public void importarExcel(DataGridView dgv,String nombreHoja)
        {
            String ruta = "";
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog openfile1 = new OpenFileDialog();
                openfile1.Filter = "Excel Files |*.xlsx";
                openfile1.Title = "Seleccione el archivo de Excel";
                if (openfile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    if (openfile1.FileName.Equals("") == false)
                    {
                        ruta = openfile1.FileName;
                    }
                }

                    conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" + ruta + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes'");
                    MyDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet$]", conn);
                    dt = new DataTable();
                    MyDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                    dgv.DataSource = dt;

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Sheet$] no es el nombre de la "tabla" que te dice cuales son las hojas?

Comment: Solo es el nombre de la hoja de un archivo que quiero abrir, si cambio esta linea y le pongo prueba1 y el archivo tiene una hoja que se nombra así, el programa lo importa, si no encuentra coincidencia me marca error.

Comment: Hay un problema ahí, si hay varias hojas, ¿cuál importa? Antes tuve el mismo problema, lo solucioné implementando una plantilla única de importación de Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Una funcion que obtiene toda la lista de hojas es:

```
conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
```

Esto te va a devolver un datatable, el cual despues podes recorrer para obtener los nombres de las hojas haciendo algo asi:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    nombre = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
}
```